# What are the orbits of satellites; circular or elliptical?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

What are the orbits of satellites; circular or elliptical?

Comment: Are you asking about all satellites, or just some satellites? And do you mean just man made satellites of the Earth or do you include natural satellites like the Moon, or satellites round other planets?

Answer (score 1):

Aren't circles special cases of ellipses? In general, orbits can be either, but are usually elliptical (at least ideally).